# Using generating functions to solve the recurrence relation for factorials

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions, factorial

Consider the recurrence relation $a_n = n a_{n-1}$ with initial condition $a_0=1$, by generating functions, I got the above expression as:

$$ A(x) =  \frac{d}{dx} (xA)$$

With $A(x) = \sum_n x^n a_n$

On solving the DE I get:

$$ A(x) =C$$

Did I do something wrong? because the answer seems quite strange..

---

Deriving the DE:

$$A(x) = a_o + a_1 x ... =\sum a_n x^n $$

$$ \frac{d}{dx}(xA)= a_o  + 2a_1 x... = \sum_n n a_{n-1} x^n$$

Multiply $x^n$ on both sides of $a_n = na_{n-1}$ and plug the above two relations, this gives:

$$A(x)=  \frac{d}{dx}(xA)$$

Or,

$$ A'(x) x = 0$$

Or, $A(x)=C$

... now what went wrong?

Comment: Yeah, that’s wrong. If you show us the steps you took to get this function, we might be to help you explain what you did wrong.

Comment: This particular power series doesn’t converge for any $x\neq0.$ You can show using any number of tests that the radius of convergence is $0.$ So it probably doesn’t have a simple form.

Comment: your solution to the differential equation is not correct. you can see this by just differentiating your proposed solution directly.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I found a mistake I had made , now correcting that, this still seems unsolvable

Comment: @MikeHawk goodpoint, I've fixed it now I think

Comment: You already wrote out the first few terms $A(x)=a_0+a_1x+...$ and $(xA)'=a_0+2a_1x+...$ from which it is clear that these series already have different $x$ coefficients So how did you conclude that these series are equal?

Comment: A(x) is the left side of the recurrence, $ \frac{d}{dx} (xA)$ is equal to the RHS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If
$A(x)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n
$
then
$xA(x)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^{n+1}
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
(xA(x))'
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)a_nx^{n}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} na_{n-1}x^{n-1}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_nx^{n-1}\\
&=\dfrac1{x}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_nx^{n}\\
&=\dfrac1{x}(A(x)-a_0)\\
\end{array}
$

so
$xA'+A
=\dfrac1{x}(A-a_0)
$.

Comment: Ah I see, it was with the index of summation

Answer (score 0):

A more direct form of marty's answer, it had to do with the index of summation:

$$a_n = n a_{n-1}$$

Multiply both sides by $x^n$ and sum from n=1 to infty,

$$ \sum_{n=1} a_n x^n = \sum_{n=1}n a_{n-1} x^n$$

We do this because $a_0$ is not defined

Comment: But then you have to do something with this,

Comment: I just wanted to point out the mistake directly , in case someone in the future gets confused @martycohen